# Explaining statements in hashCode() method in plain English

Tags: java, recursion, hashcode, gethashcode

I am trying to learn the basics of the hashCode() method in Java. I read an [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashcode) by Eugen Baeldung this morning, but I'm still having trouble with something in the code he posted. I think only the code for the method itself is needed, but I'm posting the whole code just in case.

```
package com.baeldung.hashcode.standard;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class User {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(User.class);
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public User(long id, String name, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null)
            return false;
        if (this.getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return id == user.id && (name.equals(user.name) && email.equals(user.email));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 31 * hash + (int) id;
        hash = 31 * hash + (name == null ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        hash = 31 * hash + (email == null ? 0 : email.hashCode());
        return hash;
    }
    // getters and setters here   
}
```

In the hashCode() method, the third and fourth lines confuse me. It looks like with name.hashCode() and email.hashCode() we are calling the hashCode() method on the name and the email, but we are in the middle of the hashCode() method itself when these are being called. Is this supposed to be recursive? I don't have a great grasp of recursive functions, but those are the only thing I'm aware of where you call a function inside the very function that's being called. If it's not recursive, can someone explain to me what it is? And can someone step me through how this goes about executing? I really want to understand this.

Thanks!

Comment: "s this supposed to be recursive" it's not recursive. It's calling the `hashCode` method on other objects.

Comment: Okay, so that's where I'm confused. The method hits the first two lines and has a number. But then on the third line the hash includes the value of name.hashCode(), which means it has to go back to the first and second line, and then it hits the third line again, so it has to go back to the first and second lines and so on. How can name.hashCode() return a value for the modification of hash if hash hasn't been returned yet and keeps getting stuck on line 3? Can you walk me through it?

Comment: Ignore the fact that the `hashCode` method in `User` is invoking a method called `hashCode` in `String`. It's just invoking "some other" method. It wouldn't make any difference to the flow if it were invoking some other method, say, `name.length()`, or any other method. The fact that the `hashCode` method on one object doesn't stop you invoking the `hashCode` method (or _any_ method) on another object.

Comment: "But then on the third line the hash includes the value of name.hashCode(), which means it has to go back to the first and second line, and then it hits the third line again,"
No, no, it doesn't.  It doesn't go back to those lines.  It calls _a different hashCode method_ which is in a different class.  There is no loop here.

Comment: I think I understand now. Both of your comments plus the answer below finally cleared it up for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## `String#hashCode`

Your `email` and `name` variables each hold references to a `String` object. The [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) class has its own implementation of [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()).

To quote the Javadoc for `String#hashCode`:

> Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a String object is computed as

> `s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]`

> using int arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

So, calling `email.hashCode()` or `name.hashCode()` is calling a different `hashCode` method on a different class rather than your `hashCode` method in your class.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer plus the comments above finally cleared it up for me.